# Flattening time-series IoT data with pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, multi-index, flatten

Really appreciate some help in transforming a flat Excel table into a single column series.

The Excel data reflects daily IoT sensor data (365 days/year as rows) collected hourly (24 columns of observations by hour). Current presentation from Excel file is hourly readings (columns) and dates (rows). I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I cannot directly embed images yet.

Before [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r73hR.png):
[image]

After: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaFK2.png):

[image]

I have successfully imported the .xls file with pd.read_excel, datetime type is set for the index column, and file is imported with skiprows/skipfooter

Problem #1: How to flatten file/transpose the multi-column dataframe into a single series by hour/date.
Problem #2: How to create a multiindex that combines the date of the observation with the hour of the observation.

The following images show where the data is and where it needs to go.

I apologize in advance for any lacks in posting protocols.  As I mentioned, I'm new and therefore limited in what I can post to make it easier for you to assist.

Comment: so to get this right, you have 24 entries per day, the date is the same for each entry, but you have no hour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.stack()` for this.
See [df.stack()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helping_behavior) for more information on usage

just using `df.stack()` will also automatically create a multiindex with the date and hour.